# Excell VBA célua corrseponde a outra em outra planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, web-scraping

preciso rodar uma macro dependendo da célula selecionada. todas as informações estão na mesma coluna "E", mas quando for por exemplo pra E4 preciso que a célula selecionada corresponda a outro valor em outra sheet para rodar a mesma macro com o valor de célula diferente. segue exemplo.

```
Sheets("dados1").Select
    **Range("E6").Select** (esse range precisa ser dinamico a cada célula que selecionar na mesma coluna)
    Sheets("dados3").Select
    **Range("R6").Select** (esse muda junto com a mudança da primeira folha)
    Selection.Copy
    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("dados1").Select
```

agradeço antecipadamente, sou iniciante em vba

Answer (score 0):

Fala Jairo! Então, para isso você vai precisar variar o intervalo selecionado, ao invés de fazer os eu código selecionar ele mesmo. Então você precisa identificar a célula que está selecionada com o "ActiveCell", do tipo:

Ai não sei se entendi exatamente o que seria a "outra célula na outra aba" que você descreveu. Exemplo: se a célula selecionada for a E6, na outra aba você quer a célula R6.
Se a célula selecionada for a E7, na outra aba você quer a R7? 
Porque com isso temos um padrão e nosso código pode se adaptar a isso, significa que ele sempre vai fazer na mesma linha da célula selecionada, faz sentido?
Se esse for o caso, você precisa criar uma variável para essa linha e usar ela nas duas abas. Então seu código ficaria assim:

```
Sheets("dados1").Select
    linha = ActiveCell.Row 'esse codigo pega o numero da linha da célula selecionada atualmente
    Sheets("dados3").Select
    Range("R" & linha).Select 'esse codigo seleciona a celula da coluna R com a mesma linha da celula selecionada
    Selection.Copy
    Range("X1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("dados1").Select
```

Se não for a mesma linha, você tem que identificar qual é esse padrão e criar uma variável para ele, assim seu código sempre vai funcionar independente da célula selecionada.
Obs: usei o & para concatenar os textos, para juntar o R com o valor da variável linha. Se quiser entender melhor essa parte de variável sugiro esse post aqui: https://www.hashtagtreinamentos.com/variaveis-no-vba-o-que-e-uma-variavel-no-vba/